# Can not load Dashboard, while embedding Superset Dashboard?

Tags: reactjs, apache-superset

I am able to get `GuestToken` already via `http://localhost:8088/api/v1/security/guest_token/` API. After calling API login and generate CSRF-Token

Here is my extra config at `superset_config.py`

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
ENABLE_PROXY_FIX = True
PUBLIC_ROLE_LIKE_GAMMA = True

# Dashboard embedding
GUEST_ROLE_NAME = "Gamma"
GUEST_TOKEN_JWT_SECRET = "test-guest-secret-change-me"
GUEST_TOKEN_JWT_ALGO = "HS256"
GUEST_TOKEN_HEADER_NAME = "X-GuestToken"
GUEST_TOKEN_JWT_EXP_SECONDS = 999999  # 
CORS_OPTIONS = {
  'supports_credentials': True,
  'allow_headers': ['*'],
  'resources':['*'],
  'origins': ['http://localhost:8088', 'http://localhost:8888', 'http://localhost:3000']
}
SECRET_KEY = 'JfjCBOaGVWQoJOY4_H_KYUw8AmlJz95Bb58NPh0oyd4='
HTTP_HEADERS={'X-Frame-Options':'SAMEORIGIN'}
ENABLE_CORS = True
```

Here is my FE code:

```
const fetchGuestTokenFromBackend = () => {
    return "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiL...qBN9WHK8g"
}

const Dashboard = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    embedDashboard({
      id: "0e26908b-e69c-454a-a1e9-11d343da1eb2", // given by the Superset embedding UI
      supersetDomain: "http://localhost:8088",
      mountPoint: document.getElementById("my-superset-container"), // any html element that can contain an iframe
      fetchGuestToken: () => fetchGuestTokenFromBackend(),
      dashboardUiConfig: {
        // dashboard UI config: hideTitle, hideTab, hideChartControls, filters.visible, filters.expanded (optional)
        hideTitle: true,
        filters: {
          expanded: true
        }
      }
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>This is dashboard</p>

      <div
        id="my-superset-container"
        style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

However, I keep getting the error of `localhost refused to connect`

[image]

Also I saw this in the `console.log`

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://localhost:8088') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was also running into this same issue. If you fix the first error about `X-Frame-Options` set to `sameorigin` then the following error message will resolve. The culprit is the Talisman library setting `sameorigin` as the default header response for the iframe.

You can see my solution to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76757204/13893979